# Issues importing csv column and replacing it from hash value

Tags: powershell, csv, hash, import

Please note that this data has been cleaned to prevent identifying information and considerable white space has been removed from between the commas in order to aid in readability. Lastly at the end of the TYPE column there is an additional line saying how many lines were exported which hopefully will be ignored by the script.

```
TYPE ,DATE ,TIME ,STREET ,CROSS-STREET ,X-COORD ,Y-COORD            
459 ,2015-05-03 00:00:00.000,00:58:35,FOO DR ,A RD/B CT , 0.0, 0.0
488 ,2015-05-03 00:00:00.000,02:31:54,BAR AV ,C ST/D ST , 0.0, 0.0
```

I am attempting to import this CSV using Import-CSV, convert the TYPE numeric codes into different strings. An example would be 459 becomes Apple. 488 becomes Banana and so forth. I have created a hash with the TYPE numbers as the key and the value being what I want it changed to.

So my issue is really two-fold; I have been so far unable to get the TYPE CSV column to import into the script (I've been trying an array for the most part) and I am not sure the best way to build the logic to check the array data against my hash keys and replace it with the appropriate value.

```psh
# declare filename to modify
$strFileName="test.csv"

# import the type data into its own array
$imported_CSV = Import-Csv $strFileName 

# populate hash
$conversion_Hash =  @{
            187 = Homicide;
            211 = Robbery;
            245 = Assault;
            451 = Arson;
            459 = Burglary;
            484 = Larceny;
            487 = Grand Theft;
            488 = Petty Theft;
            10851 = Stolen Vehicle;
            HS = Drug;
}

# perform the conversion
foreach ($record in $imported_CSV)
{
    $conversion_Hash[$record.Type]
}
```

This has no logic and just contains the code that was presented in the answer below. Note that I addressed that it doesn't work in the comments below.

Comment: Yep....show us what you've got so far, you might not be far off of a solution

Comment: Does your real data contain those spaces in the type column? I think you column would be `type_` and not just `type`. Under score is there to show a space

Comment: Hi Micheal. I rolled back you edit so that people can clearly see the problem and the solution. I get what you were doing but it is more useful to others the way it is now.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an example of what you are looking for:

```
$hashTable = @{459= Apple; 488= Banana;} 
$csv = import-csv <file>
foreach($record in $csv)
{
$hashTable[$record.Type] #returns hash value
}
```

Output:

```
Apple
Banana
```

Comment: I noticed that foreach($record in $csv} <-- is ending in a bracket rather than in a parenthesis. I tried it your way and replacing it with the  parenthesis and it didn't work in either case. I did get an interesting null error though for each line of the CSV. `Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Users\User\PCCU.ps1:38 char:19
+     $conversion_Hash[ <<<< $record.Type]
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray`

Answer (score 0):

So we have several little issues here. The two big ones are your source file and the your hashtable keys are integers and not strings.

```psh
# declare filename to modify
$strFileName="c:\temp\point.csv"

# import the type data into its own array
$imported_CSV = (Get-Content $strFileName) -replace "\s*,\s*","," | ConvertFrom-Csv

# populate hash
$conversion_Hash =  @{
            "187" = "Homicide";
            "211" = "Robbery";
            "245" = "Assault";
            "451" = "Arson";
            "459" = "Burglary";
            "484" = "Larceny";
            "487" = "Grand Theft";
            "488" = "Petty Theft";
            "10851" = "Stolen Vehicle";
            "HS" = "Drug";
}

# perform the conversion
foreach ($record in $imported_CSV)
{
    $conversion_Hash[$record.Type]
}
```

**Output from naughty people**

```
Burglary
Petty Theft
```

I don't know if your source file looks like it does in your question but there is a bunch of whitespace there that will be giving you a hassle. Namely you dont have a TYPE column but a "TYPE " (without the spaces). Same goes for the other columns. Data is affected as well. It's not 459 but "459 "(without the spaces).

To fix that I check the file and replace all space surrounding the commas with just the comma.

```
TYPE,DATE,TIME,STREET,CROSS-STREET,X-COORD,Y-COORD            
459,2015-05-03 00:00:00.000,00:58:35,FOO DR,A RD/B CT,0.0,0.0
488,2015-05-03 00:00:00.000,02:31:54,BAR AV,C ST/D ST,0.0,0.0
```

If your data already looks like that then you need to be careful posting this stuff in your question. Onto the other issue with your comparison

You will see I have quoted almost everything in that hashtable. I had to for the values as they were being taken as commands otherwise. I also quoted the keys as the csv table contains string and not integers. I would have just casted to `[int]` to avoid the whole issue but one of your keys is called "HS" which does not look like a number to me :).

**What I might have done**

Just to play a little I might have added another note property to the list called `TypeAsString` which would add a column.

```
# perform the conversion
$imported_CSV | ForEach-Object{
    $_ |  Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "TypeAsString" -Value $conversion_Hash[$_.Type] -PassThru
}
```

So the output from one item would look like this

```
TYPE         : 459
DATE         : 2015-05-03 00:00:00.000
TIME         : 00:58:35
STREET       : FOO DR
CROSS-STREET : A RD/B CT
X-COORD      : 0.0
Y-COORD      : 0.0
TypeAsString : Burglary
```

I could have made a more dynamic property like a script property, so that changes in `$conversion_Hash` are updated instantly, but this should suffice for what you need.

Comment: Well in my first paragraph of my post I mention that all this data has been cleaned of identifying info :) Also I mentioned that I purposefully trimmed the whitespace for readability. I didn't think to trim the whitespace in the CSV itself which was a good call as far as I can tell. I took your suggestions and completed the code with an export-csv command at the end and modified the conversion logic to commit the changes. Thanks for all your help.